# Creating list of user's groups and nested groups in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory

I am running into a problem in VBScript where my login script is only seeing groups a user is directly in, not nested groups the user is indirectly in. For example, if User1 is in GroupA, and GroupA is in GroupB, the script does not recognize that User1 is also a member of GroupB.

```
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUserName = objNetwork.UserName
strComputerName = objNetwork.ComputerName
strUserDomain = objNetwork.UserDomain
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strUserDomain & "/" & strUserName & ",user"
strGroupList = ""
For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
    strGroupList = strGroupList & "[" + objGroup.Name & "] " 
    GetNested(objGroup)
Next
```

GetNested is defined as follows (got this from a Hey, Scripting Guy article with slight modification)

```
Function GetNested(objGroup)
    On Error Resume Next
    colMembers = objGroup.GetEx("memberOf")
    For Each strMember in colMembers
        strPath = "LDAP://" & strMember
        Set objNestedGroup = GetObject(strPath)
        strGroupList = strGroupList & "[" + objNestedGroup.Name & "] "
        GetNested(objNestedGroup)
    Next
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. The problem here seemed to stem from the mixing of WinNT and LDAP.

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
```

Using LDAP to create objUser worked. Hope this helps someone else as well